# UDP Packet arriving different than sent

Tags: java, udp, packet, corruption

So this is a very straightforward question.
I am sending a packet that looks like this:

```
Nicba1010;375.40018;381.3502;100.0;100.0
```

And it arrives like this:

```
Nicba1010;375.40018;381.3502;100.0;100.00.0
```

I'm programming in Java and I just adapted a simple tutorial.
Its practically a game and the last parameter should never change, but it does.
When I connect 2 clients to the server, well then its a total mess.
I would very appreciate your help.
Sincerely Nicba1010

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are copying the data into a byte[] and you are not looking at how many bytes was copied.  I.e. there is some byte left over from a previous packet and if you only look at the bytes copied, it will be correct.

Comment: you are totally correct sir, I never reset the byte array

Comment: @UraniumDevelopers If you are converting to a String, you can use the constructor `new String(bytes, 0, length, charset);`  This way you don't need reset the bytes, just use the bytes which are valid.

Comment: I'm so fricking greatful man, been looking at this for an hour, made the byte arrays global not local. Dumb me :|

Comment: @UraniumDevelopers Remember, a computer expert is someone who has made all the mistakes before. ;)

Comment: @UraniumDevelopers It's not about 'reset[ting] the byte array', it is about using `DatagramPacket.getLength()` as the length, instead of the length of the byte array.